# Drawbacks of adding nbf claim in JWT token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

We have some clock skew problem so we have decided to add `nbf` claim in `JWT` which should solve the problem up to some extant.

But before that I just want to know what could be possible drawbacks for adding this optional claim in `JWT` token. Please suggest if you have faced any problem with this claim in real system.

Answer (score 2):

From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.5

> 4.1.5.  "nbf" (Not Before) Claim
>
> The "nbf" (not before) claim identifies the time before which the
> JWT    MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of the
> "nbf"    claim requires that the current date/time MUST be after or
> equal to    the not-before date/time listed in the "nbf" claim.
> Implementers MAY    provide for some small leeway, usually no more
> than a few minutes, to    account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a
> number containing a    NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is
> OPTIONAL.

Hence adding the `nbf` claim could make the system with the clock skew reject the token even though it is valid. I don't see how it solves the problem that you mention. A JWT with no `nbf` claim is easier to consume for other systems, even when there's a clock skew, though arguably less secure.